# How to handle multiple database accesses?

Tags: delphi, advantage-database-server

In my program I have multiple databases. One is fixed and cannot be changed, but there are also some others, the so called user databases.
I thought now I have to start for every database one connection and to connect to each data dictionary. How is it possible to connect to more than one database with one connection by handing over the data dictionary filename? Btw. I am using a local server.

thank you very much,

André

P.S.: Okay I might find the answer to my problem.
The Key word is CreateDDLink. The procedure is connecting to another data dictionary, but before a master dictionary has to be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links may be what you are looking for as you indicated in the question.  You can use the API or SQL to create a permanent link alias, or you can dynamically create links on the fly.

I would recomend reviewing this specific help file page: [Using Tables from Multiple Data Dictionaries](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/WebHelp/Advantage10.1/index.html?master_using_tables_from_multiple_data_dictionaries.htm)

for a permanent alias (using SQL) look at sp_createlink.  You can either create the link to authenticate the current user or set up the link to authenticate as a specific user.  Then use the link name in your SQL statements.
select * from linkname.tablename

Or dynamically you can use the following which will authenticate the current user:
select * from "..\dir\otherdd.add".table1

However, links are only available to SQL.  If you want to use the table directly (i.e. via a TAdsTable component) you will need to create views.  See KB [080519-2034](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?Key=17&RefNo=080519-2034).  The KB mentions you can't post updates if the SQL statement for the view results in a static cursor, but you can get around that by creating triggers on the view.